# Deleting lines matching regex along with 2 previous lines

Tags: perl, sed, lines

I have a file where I need to remove the 2 lines before the regex foo.

```
bad 1
foo
good 1
good 2
good 3
bad 2
bad 3
foo
good 4
good 5
good 6
bad 4
bad 5
foo
good 7
bad 6
bad 7
foo
good 8
good 9
good 10
bad 8
bad 9
foo
good11
```

I can do it easily with sed :

```
casper_mint@casper-mint-dell /tmp $ cat dddd | sed '/bad/ , /foo/d'
good 1
good 2
good 3
good 4
good 5
good 6
good 7
good 8
good 9
good 10
good11
```

How can I do this in perl?

Comment: Does your data have this blank lines?

Comment: @Jotne It would seem so.  Given that the output contains pair of consecutive blank lines when the lines between the two patterns is deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a one liner:

```
print -ne 'push @b, $_; @b = () if /^foo$/; print shift @b if @b > 2; END {print @b};' file
```

Or demonstrated in a full script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @b;

while (<DATA>) {
    push @b, $_;
    @b = () if /^foo/;
    print shift @b if @b > 2;
}

END {print @b};

__DATA__
bad 1
foo
good 1
good 2
good 3
bad 2
bad 3
foo
good 4
good 5
good 6
bad 4
bad 5
foo
good 7
bad 6
bad 7
foo
good 8
good 9
good 10
bad 8
bad 9
foo
good11
```

Both Output:

```
good 1
good 2
good 3
good 4
good 5
good 6
good 7
good 8
good 9
good 10
good11
```

Answer (score 6):

In `perl`, you could make use of the range operator:

```
perl -ne 'print unless /bad/ .. /foo/' filename
```

would give the same output as `sed`.

---

You may also want to look at [`s2p`](http://perldoc.perl.org/s2p.html).

Related: [How can I pull out lines between two patterns that are themselves on different lines?](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq6.html#How-can-I-pull-out-lines-between-two-patterns-that-are-themselves-on-different-lines-)